# Question about a presentation on substructural logic (negation modulo two kinds of residuation)

Tags: philosophy-of-logic, negation, non-classical-logic, substructural-logic

I've been reading through [this slide-based presentation on substructural logic](https://www.logic.at/tbilisi11/slides/ono.pdf) and I'm delightfully perplexed by the following section:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**What is the use to which the two given flavors of negation can be put?** They look like logical division, I would suppose, in counterpoint to [logical subtraction](https://philosophy.princeton.edu/sites/g/files/toruqf2381/files/phi537_f19-5.pdf) and mathematical division. But so how far is the analogy to be pressed? I assume that *a*\0 is not strictly "undefined," here, and the slash is in the other direction compared to division "proper" anyway, but is that kind of expression meant to invoke the distinction between the undefined and the indeterminate re: 1/0 vs. 0/0? (The presentation appears to leave off from the topic so far as I have yet gone through it.)

Comment: Chasing the rabbit down the hole of relevance logic, eh? :D

Comment: @JD IIRC Zack Weber, the founder of paraconsistent set theory, was a student under a prominent early relevance logician, who told him something like, "Relevance logic is the key to the universe." Overdramatic, hopefully tongue-in-cheek, but worth my time nevertheless to consider to some degree ;)

Comment: There is no rabbit, just the hole.

Comment: Both residuations have natural interpretations as "logical division" in the calculus of binary relations, see [Pratt, Origins of the Calculus of Binary Relations, pp. 2 and 4](https://www.academia.edu/29772886/Origins_of_the_Calculus_of_Binary_Relations). They go back to Birkhoff and are defined on general residuated lattices, Wikipedia gives a [number of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residuated_lattice#Examples). If you choose a logic with a lattice where x\y and y/x are distinct you'll interpret those two negations.

Comment: These two kinds of negations are naturally arised in substructural logics sequent calculus without any structural rule which has algebraic isomorphism known as Full-Lambek residuated lattice with a fixed bottom element (but no top element like Heyting algebra) wherefrom its class both classes of all the familiar Heyting algebras for intuitionistic logic and Boolean algebras for classic logic are its subvarieties of algebras. Implication is algebraic division, thus adding temporal noncommutativity your 1st negation is from past to now, while 2nd left residual implies from future falsehood...

Comment: Once understood the lattice order representation of logical implication, to further understand the transfer (adjoint) property between division and monoidal multiplication you need to refer to adjoint functors (left and right) of category theory, above lattice multiplication is the left adjoint while residual division is its right adjoint pair. And assuming generic noncommutativity of the lattice monoidal multiplication in substructural FL lattice, 2 flavors of multiplication and their corresponding division arise here thus bears 2 types of negations…